# Show current image enlarge on click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, lightbox

This is my code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" BackColor="Gray" BorderColor="#666666"
                                BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3"                      
                                CellSpacing="2" RepeatLayout="Flow" Font-Names="Verdana"
                                Font-Size="Small" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="3"  
                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                Width="100%">

<FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White"
                                 HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <HeaderTemplate> Employee Details </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" BorderWidth="2px" />
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%--imp---*********---------********--%>    
      <a data-lightbox="roadtrip" href='<%# Eval("Path", "~/PlayerImages/{0}") %>' > 
         <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("Path",
                   "~/PlayerImages/{0}") %>' Width="50%" Height="50%" />
      <%--imp---*********---------********--%>
      </a><br />
      <b>Employee Name:</b>
      <asp:Label ID="lblCName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>

      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

the area of code where i marked as imp
in the first line i had set `href='<%# Eval("Path", "~/PlayerImages/{0}") %>'` because i want to show enlarge image of the current image but it is not working.
The reason for this is i think data is not bound to that `href` because when i am passing a fixed path in place of `Eval` it displays me that image.
I dont know how to do it. 
please suggest me solutions.

Comment: you can use `literal` control and form the html in `ItemDatabound` event then replace the literal text with this html

Comment: can you please give a example to do this

Comment: what data source you are binding to data list?

Comment: i am binding image path and name to the list

Comment: yeah, that is what i'm asking like it is DataTable or dataview some thing else?

Comment: iam using dataset to bind data to datalist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `DataList` definition like below

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" BackColor="Gray" BorderColor="#666666"
                            BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3"                      
                            CellSpacing="2" RepeatLayout="Flow" Font-Names="Verdana"
                            Font-Size="Small" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="3"  
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                            Width="100%" ItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound">
```

then change `ItemTemplate` like below

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ltrlLightBox"/>
  <b>Employee Name:</b>
  <asp:Label ID="lblCName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

access the `literal control` in `ItemDatabound event`

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Literal ltrlLightBox = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("ltrlLightBox");
        DataRow drow = (DataRow)e.Item.DataItem;
        ltrlLightBox.Text = "<a data-lightbox=\"roadtrip\" href=\"PlayerImages/" + drow["Path"].ToString() + "\" > <img src=\"PlayerImages/" + drow["Path"].ToString() + "\" width=\"50%\" height=\"50%\" /></a><br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: your code works but with littile modifications i made update in your answer thanks